# Programmatically delete an Access macro with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to programmatically delete an Access Macro (or Form or Report) via VBA.

The AllMacros collection (and the associated `Application.Containers().Documents collections`) appear to be Read Only.

I can delete Tables and Queries simply enough, but the other object types are eluding me.

I'm even prepared to use the underlying system tables if I know where to go.

Comment: Which version of Access are you using? The above implies 97.

Comment: It's Access 2010 operating on an Access 2000 mdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acMacro, "MyMacro"
```

Comment: Doh!  I plead "snow blindness".  Once your mind gets set on a particular track, it's hard to shift!   Thanks a bunch!